# How to delete value from certain cells of the current editing row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
I have a simple gridview:
A sql datasource to bind data from table data to gridview.
```

On gridview row updating I would like to clear the cell values from certain columns of the current editing row, so the values should be also deleted from the table data. How can I do that?

Something like:

```
SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "Delete value from column1,column2 where rowid=@rowid"; //I need the right statment
SqlDataSource1.Delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is something confusing here. If you want to "detele" 2 column values, then you can simply make them null :

```
 UPDATE table
    SET column1 = null,
        column2 = null
  WHERE rowid = @rowid;
```

or just delete the whole row

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE rowid = @rowid;
```